# How do I change the aspect ratio of gnuplot output?

Tags: scaling, graphs, gnuplot

How do I change the aspect ratio of the canvas of a gnuplot plot in LaTeX using the gnuplottex package?

The following changes the aspect ratio of the output but not the canvas size, thus leaving a margin above and below the graph.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[miktex,cleanup]{gnuplottex}   %miktex option for my editor
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex]
    set size ratio 0.2
    plot [0:2*pi] sin(x) with lines linewidth 2 title 'Sine'
    \end{gnuplot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above]

Comment: You can use the `terminaloptions` parameter to set the canvas size: `\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex, terminaloptions={size 14cm, 4cm}]`. But I don't know how to pass the `\textwidth` into this parameter.

Comment: Sorry about the textwidth, it was about a question I wanted to ask earlier. I changed the title accordingly. And thanks for the workaround.

Comment: My earlier comment is likewise valid for the new question. The terminal option `size` is used to change the canvas. Unfortunately, there is no option `crop` for the `gnuplottex` package. So you may need to play around with the gnuplot margins e.g. `set tmargin` or `set size` (without `ratio`) and `set origin`.

Comment: @Don Congrats on the 10k.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not fluent in `gnuplot`, so this could be refined. You *can* pass parameters based on `\textwidth`, as long as they are in the options to `gnuplot`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[cleanup]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\convertlen}{ O{cm} m }
 {
  \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { #2 } { 1 #1 } cm
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{gnuplot}[
      terminal=cairolatex,
      terminaloptions={size \convertlen{\textwidth},\convertlen{.3\textwidth}}
    ]
    set size ratio 0.3
    plot [0:2*pi] sin(x) with lines linewidth 2 title 'Sine'
    \end{gnuplot}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The `\convertlen` macro is just to provide `gnuplot` with something it knows (centimeters, in this case). The command has also an optional argument for specifying another unit.

[image]

Comment: I get an error with your code: `! Undefined control sequence.
\convertlen code #1#2->\dim_to_unit:nn` I guess some recent change in `expl3` made `\dim_to_unit` unknown?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, there has been a change. Thanks for noting.

Answer (score 4):

In order to set the canvas size, you must pass a `size` option to `gnuplot`. I don't know a way to cut off the margins automatically, this would require a `crop` option for the `gnuplottex` package.

So, the solution I can present you is to set the size manually, and adjust the margins from within `gnuplot` with e.g. `set lmargin` and `set rmargin`. You can also use the `pdf` option for the `cairolatex` terminal, then you don't need `epstopdf`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cleanup]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
  \centering  
  \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex, terminaloptions={pdf size 12cm,4cm}]
     set lmargin 4.5
     set rmargin 0.1
     plot [0:2*pi] sin(x) with lines linewidth 2 title 'Sine'
  \end{gnuplot}
\end{minipage}%

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use

```
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex]
set size 1,0.6
plot [0:2*pi] sin(x) with lines linewidth 2 title 'Sine'
\end{gnuplot}
```

Maybe needs some fiddling at the beginning, but I think it's easier in the end than messing around with margins.