# How to avoid underfull \hbox when using subfigures?

Tags: boxes, warnings, subcaption

When compiling the MWE below with pdflatex, I get the warnings `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 26--27` and `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 36--37`.

I tried to avoid this by using `\hfill` between the subfigures, but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\convertlen}{ O{cm} m }
 {
  \dim_to_unit:nn { #2 } { 1 #1 } cm
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
  \begin{gnuplot}[terminal = cairolatex, terminaloptions = {size \convertlen{\textwidth},\convertlen{.3\textheight}}]
   plot sin(x)
  \end{gnuplot}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:1a}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
  \begin{gnuplot}[terminal = cairolatex, terminaloptions = {size \convertlen{\textwidth},\convertlen{.3\textheight}}]
   plot sin(x)
  \end{gnuplot}
  \caption{Another subfigure}
  \label{fig:1b}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code gives me the error `! Undefined control sequence.
\convertlen code #1#2->\dim_to_unit:nn `

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I need the `\convertlen` command to specify the width of the gnuplot graph. I found the code for `\convertlen` [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133709/how-do-i-change-the-aspect-ratio-of-gnuplot-output/133726#133726) and don't fully understand it. But it does what I want, except the underfull boxes.

Comment: I don't know why, but changing both occurrences of `\convertlen{\textwidth}` to `\convertlen{.99\textwidth}` makes the warnings go away.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks, inserting `.99` worked. Who would have thought that you need a smaller figure to get rid of the `underfull box` warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add

```
\showboxdepth3
\showboxbreadth10
\tracingonline1
```

to see which box is underfull you see

```
\hbox(178.66272+0.0)x188.21371
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\hbox(178.66272+0.0)x187.69623
..\special{ps: currentpoint currentpoint translate 1 1 scale neg exch neg exch 
t\ETC.}
..\hbox(178.66272+0.0)x0.0, glue set - 187.69623fil
...\hbox(178.66272+0.0)x187.69623 []
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
..\special{ps: currentpoint currentpoint translate 1 1 div 1 1 div scale neg ex
c\ETC.}
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

So the line is trying to be 188.21371pt  but the box with the plot is 187.69623pt  the only glue on the line is `\rightskip` and that is zero, so the box is underful.

That's slightly odd as a one line paragraph usually has `\parfillskip`  at the end but that has been removed here somewhere in the verbatim handling for gnuplot.

rather than debug exactly where `\parfillskip` went, a simpler fix is to make `\rightskip` non zero, and if you uncomment the `%\centering` the warning goes away.

(I updated the name of `\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn`)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\convertlen}{ O{cm} m }
 {
  \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { #2 } { 1 #1 } cm
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%\showoutput
\showboxdepth3
\showboxbreadth10
\tracingonline1
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
%\centering
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal = cairolatex, terminaloptions = {size \convertlen{\textwidth},\convertlen{.3\textheight}}]
   plot sin(x)
  \end{gnuplot}
  \caption{A subfigure}
  \label{fig:1a}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
  \begin{gnuplot}[terminal = cairolatex, terminaloptions = {size \convertlen{\textwidth},\convertlen{.3\textheight}}]
   plot sin(x)
  \end{gnuplot}
  \caption{Another subfigure}
  \label{fig:1b}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```